# Input number masking

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Masking of input number is not working in IE.

Code which is working in other browsers:

JsFiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/ca3nru7f/

```js
$scope.properties.originalInputVal = result;
$('.value,.number').click(function() {
  if ($scope.properties.inputKey && $scope.properties.inputKey.length == 12) {
    $scope.properties.originalInputVal = ''
    $scope.properties.inputKey = ''
    result = ''
    $('.number').val('')
    $('.value').val('')
    $('.value').css({
      'color': 'initial'
    })
  }
})
if ($scope.properties.inputKey && $scope.properties.inputKey.length == 12) {
  $('.value').css({
    'color': 'transparent'
  })
} else {
  $('.value').css({
    'color': 'initial'
  })
}
```